# Class not found Exception after exporting Exsisting class to JAR

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jar

I have created a web application in java and is working fine. But i want to Convert few classes in JAR format, so that the code inside the jar is not visible to others.

I have totally 5 classes. 3 classes (CreateFile,ProcessFile,HouseWork) belong to a package "FilePackage" remaining two classes are SFTPEngine and ExecEngine they belong to Package "PuttyEngine".

I selected all these classes and gave export as JAR and named it mytool.jar.

Now i deleted all these classes from eclipse and added the jar. In the Eclipse IDE after configuring the BuildPath no error was displayed. when I run the application on tomcat server from the IDE itself I get **ClassNotFoundException**

How Do I export those classes into a JAR file and use them. These classes use functions from other classes as well. ie SFTPEngine class will access fucntions from others classes and other classes also wil be accesing the functions in SFTPEngine class.

I am not using any build tool. Cause I cannot use them in my office , I need to get permission from admin, so is there any way to do this work without build tools like ANT or MAVEN

Comment: My guess is that you didn't get that JAR in the WAR file that is deployed to Tomcat.  You're depending on your IDE too much without understanding what it does for you.

Comment: No even in the tomcat lib folder i added my jar and while exporting war i made sure that i exported along with my jars

Comment: Not the Tomcat /lib; it belongs in your app's WAR.  Should be in the WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: I see no advantage to having these in a JAR unless you intend to share them with another app as you would a 3rd party.  Try it without the JAR; compile the classes to the WEB-INF/classes folder.

Comment: you need to share exact exception details,what you get while running.because there should be many possibility for e.g if your class using any third party jar,then might be that third party jar is not available in you own build jar.So just share the Exception and class related to that Exception

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, click on your web project / Properties / Tab "Deployment Assembly".

Add your JAR here.

After that, in the server Tab, when you expand the server, then you can expand the web project, and you should see your JAR.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include your jar under webapps/ under Tomcat installation directory if you're running Tomcat outside Eclipse.